# How can we vary two dependent variables independently in the partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider the smooth function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Applying the chain rule yields

$$\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \mathrm{d}u + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \mathrm{d}v.$$

This makes perfect sense to me for the independent variables $u$ and $v$. However let $u = x(t)$ and let $v = y(t)$. Then how does it the partial derivative

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$$

make any sense. Because if $u = x(t)$ is varied, $v = y(t)$ cannot be held constant. Or is $v$ allowed to be any function when taking the partial derivative with respect to $u$, i.e.

$$\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right|_{u = x(t)}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $u=x(t)$ and $v=y(t)$ then you cannot consider $u$ and $v$ independent anymore. In such case, according to the chain rule, the derivative of the composite function 
$$
g(t)=f(x(t),y(t))
$$
is given by
$$
g'(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}x'(t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}y'(t)
$$
where the partial derivatives of $f$ **are calculated at the point $(x(t),y(t))$**. That is, you compute them normally, assuming that $u$ and $v$ are your independent variables, and then you **evaluate at $(x(t),y(t))$.**